# What would be the cause of openvpn network fault?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, openvpn

We have openvpn network for aproximately 1200 client connections. Basically everything is running fine but there exists 0-4 collapses per day (which occurs randomly), when we looses majority/all of connections. 
There is a cron job which checks once per minute how many client connections exists:

```
echo "status 3" | /bin/nc 127.0.0.1 5001 -q 1 | /bin/grep CLIENT_LIST | /bin/grep 10.10. | /usr/bin/wc -l
```

one days result is:

```
Mon Nov 23 23:24:02 EET 2015     1201
Mon Nov 23 23:25:02 EET 2015     312
Mon Nov 23 23:26:02 EET 2015     1201


Tue Nov 24 02:46:02 EET 2015     1196
Tue Nov 24 02:47:02 EET 2015     0
Tue Nov 24 02:48:02 EET 2015     1198


Tue Nov 24 05:45:02 EET 2015     1197
Tue Nov 24 05:46:02 EET 2015     324
Tue Nov 24 05:47:02 EET 2015     1196


Tue Nov 24 05:55:02 EET 2015     1199
Tue Nov 24 05:56:04 EET 2015     0
Tue Nov 24 05:57:02 EET 2015     35
Tue Nov 24 05:58:02 EET 2015     208
Tue Nov 24 05:59:02 EET 2015     369
Tue Nov 24 06:00:02 EET 2015     517
Tue Nov 24 06:01:02 EET 2015     636
Tue Nov 24 06:02:02 EET 2015     739
Tue Nov 24 06:03:02 EET 2015     845
Tue Nov 24 06:04:02 EET 2015     945
Tue Nov 24 06:05:02 EET 2015     1042
Tue Nov 24 06:06:02 EET 2015     1121
Tue Nov 24 06:07:02 EET 2015     1141
```

When "black out" happens the log says:

```
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 11.111.111.111:59208 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 11.111.111.111:59208 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 11.111.111.111:59208 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
Nov 24 05:56:02  ovpn-openvpn[12639]: last message repeated 3 times
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 222.222.222.222:34914 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 222.222.222.222:34914 LZO compression initialized
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 222.222.222.222:34914 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:166 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 222.222.222.222:34914 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 222.222.222.222:34914 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 0,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-server'
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 222.222.222.222:34914 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client'
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 222.222.222.222:34914 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '14168603'
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 222.222.222.222:34914 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '504e774e'
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 222.222.222.222:34914 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]222.222.222.222:34914, sid=e60171c4 e7222269
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 kernel: [45070269.509652] IN=tun0 OUT=eth1 MAC= SRC=10.10.143.155 DST=10.1.1.11 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=50374 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=502 DPT=54773 WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0 
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:47624 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:47624 LZO compression initialized
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:47624 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:166 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:47624 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:47624 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 0,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-server'
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:47624 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client'
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:47624 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '14168603'
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:47624 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '504e774e'
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:47624 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]44.444.444.44:47624, sid=f2f58219 caddd889
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
Nov 24 05:56:03 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
Nov 24 05:56:03 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 1000000713/333.333.33.333:58655 MULTI: Learn: 10.200.6.150 -> 1000000713/333.333.33.333:58655
Nov 24 05:56:03 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
Nov 24 05:56:04 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[19031]: Current Parameter Settings:
Nov 24 05:56:04 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[19031]:   config = '/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf'
Nov 24 05:56:04 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[19031]:   mode = 1
.
.
.
spits out server.conf file
```

To be clear:

```
Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:59208 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
    Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:59208 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
    Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: 44.444.444.44:59208 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
    Nov 24 05:56:02 xxxxxx1 ovpn-openvpn[12639]: read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
```

..exist there because of badly synchronized certificate valid startTimes. (After electric failure clients reset their clocks
    to default values which are out from certificates valid range) -presumably not the cause of the main problem?

- After the watchdog detects zero connections the openvpn service is forced to restart:

  /usr/bin/killall -9 openvpn

  /bin/sh /etc/init.d/openvpn restart
- We have been logging network interface in 1 second resolution and there isn't any failures
- We have been logging iptables and within dropped packets there is nothing there to suggest to openvpn connections
- After openvpn restart all clients reconnects normally and everything is running fine until next collapse.
- Mostly our clients are either routers with dd-wrt or embedded linux with openvpn.
- Server.conf:

  ```
  local xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
  port 1194
  ;proto tcp
  proto udp
  ;dev tap
  dev tun
  ;dev-node MyTap
  ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
  cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
  key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
  dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem
  mode server
  ifconfig 10.10.128.1 10.10.128.2
  ifconfig-pool 10.10.128.4 10.10.255.255
  route 10.10.128.0 255.255.128.0
  route 10.200.0.0 255.255.0.0
  push "route 10.200.0.0 255.255.0.0"
  push "route 10.10.128.0 255.255.128.0"
  push "route 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0"
  client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
  keepalive 7 50
  tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0 # This file is secret
  tls-server
  comp-lzo no
  verb 5
  topology p2p
  management localhost 5001
  crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
  script-security 2
  client-disconnect "/usr/bin/php /root/cron/connect_disconnect.php disconnect"
  client-connect "/usr/bin/php /root/cron/connect_disconnect.php connect"
  ```

Please, would you have any suggestions how to log/track/hunt possible causes of this kind of behaviour?

Thanks for advance

- Jani H